# Converting a Hexadecimal string to a Binary Value in installshield 2009

Tags: installshield, installshield-2009, installscript

Setting binary registry values in installshield needs binary string values, However usually binary values in installscript is presented in hexadecimal forms.

So following code is not correct if you want to use RegDBSetKeyValueEx (Just Sample and value is not correct) because it is expecting binary string.

```
  szName = "DefaultLaunchPermission";
  nType  = REGDB_BINARY;
  szKeyValue1 = "0100048070";
  RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szKey, szName, nType, szKeyValue1, StrLength(szKeyValue1));
```

I've already found [binary to hex function](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q105496)  but I'm looking to find hex to binary to convert my hex-form string to binary string before passing them to RegDBSetKeyValueEx.

If some body has already developed that I'd appreciate.